# Is there a way to compress html output created via php?

Tags: php, html

For a school project we are supposed to compress our html output generated via php. Is there any way to do this? For example, the code below should not have any white spaces. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is there are particular shortage of [answers to this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+apache+minify+php+html+output)?

Comment: In this case, trim the string. Hard to say, to see not any code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code is not clear. However, as far as I understood you are asking for this solution. You want to remove spaces from text.

```
$var = "Hello World!"; //var with spaces

$removespacefromvar = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $var); //This code gonna remove the white space from $var 

?>
<div><?= $removespacefromvar ?></div>
<?php
 //This will output the final text where we have removed space
```

The `<?=` icon is a short php tag.
Know More about preg_replace here: [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is no good idea, because spaces in the string would be removed. `trim($var)` would be more efficient to remove them on start and end.

Comment: Yes, all the spaces wil be removed from the string. So what is the problem here? He asked for it. He wanted to compress it. The answer has worked too thats why it has Been accepted answer.

Comment: The problem is, when within (!) the string more spaces are really wanted, they also get removed. Trimming takes care removing only from begin and end.

Comment: compressing Doesn't mean to remove sace only from begin and end, it means to remove all spaces

Comment: No! Compression means regaining everything as it was and not to change values. "GewohnheitensindzuerstSpinneweben-dannDrähte" would be **wrong** removing all spaces.

Comment: but it doesnt apply for him: "For example, the code below should not have any white spaces"

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. It's not optimal, but is good enough for me:

```
$html = preg_replace('/(\n+|\t+|\s{2, })/misU', ' ', $html)
```

It removes newlines and tabs, as well as sets of 2 or more spaces.